# Git - how to remove a file from a single branch

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

I have a repo that I have a master branch which will end up containing the "core" of this app, and client branches that will contain the core, and additionally the public side that contains all the assets, styling, and front-end views.  I know this can be done as I have tested it with a local repo.  BUT the problem is I'm starting from a fully built out client app, I'm wanting to carve out a few folders from the master branch w/o propogating those deletes to other branches when I merge outward to the client branches, updates to the core of the system.

So, in more simple terms, How do I remove a file from one branch without propogating that delete to other branches upon a merge?

Comment: IMO you should use submodules to separate client specifics (assets, etc). Manually dealing with that is an invitation to disaster.

Comment: I'm open to all options, please explain what you mean, maybe more of an answer.

Comment: I posted it as real answer so we can discuss it and I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a fresh repository for the core, and remaking the client branches, as this structure was an afterthought.  So I was trying to do this backwards.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you should use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to separate client specifics (assets, etc). Manually dealing with that is an invitation to disaster

Create a separate repository for each client, and add a submodule pointing to your core, and for anything else that is shared between them. Code that isn't shared between clients doesn't need to belong to the core, nor to other shared submodules. It means each (current) branch corresponding to a client has to become a separate repository. After all, they're independent of each other, and that's the whole point.

You'll end up with this repository hierarchy:

```
       core
        /\
       /  \
client1    client2
```

**UPDATE**:

**IMPORTANT:** backup everything so you don't get into trouble if something goes wrong.

All this is highly dependent on your scenario. But the following is an idea of how to accomplish what I described in a non-Windows system:

**1)** Split your current repository into various repositories (e.g.: core, client1, client2, etc):

```
cp -R original_repo copy_repo
cd copy_repo
git checkout desired_branch
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter desired_directory -- --all
```

Repeat this for each client directory too. At the end of this step, you'll have a separate repository for each of these parts (core, client1, client2, etc).

**2)** Add the new split core repository as a submodule to each of your client1..clientN repositories:

```
git submodule add <path_for_core_alone>
git submodule init # Add the submodule to .git/config
git submodule update # Clone the core repository
```

**3)** Coffee & profit.

Comment: please explain what a "submodule" is.

Comment: sounds good, but how would I implement this in practice, read the docs, but sometimes it's a bit foreign, laymen's terms maybe?

Comment: @jondavidjohn: sorry, what specifically you didn't understand?

Comment: implementation steps, how I would update from the core on the client branches, and also if this will affect my directory structure.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: updated to give you an idea of how to accomplish. Your directory structure is likely to change reasonably, but this is for a noble reason.

Comment: ok, I'm seeing it now, so the core submodule will have to have its own directory?  I'm working with a not-so modular MVC framework so I have 'public' directories inside my models, views, and controller directories, and then a public assets directory also.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: correct. Well, you could solve that by extending your classes, but it might be an overkill. Which MVC & language you're using?

Comment: php/Codeigniter, I think I'm going to make the upgrade to 2.0.0 which allows the use of 'packages' which are just condensed alternate locations for m,v,and c's

Comment: Update: CI 2.0 packages do not support controllers and views, only for libraries models and helpers, I just ended up re-setting up my repo from the core out, so I have the core (master) and then I have client1 that is the core, but I have added frontend files to it, so to update the core of client sites, I just always merge outward, from the core, never the other way around.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: you could symlink the controllers & views' directory from your core to an auxiliar directory within your client projects and then include or extend them accordingly. Do you think this is either doable & acceptable?

Comment: this didnt answer the question

Comment: @RobertLemiesz: AFAIK Git doesn't allow you to delete a file from a branch and expect merge not to delete it from the target branch. Therefore I tried to provide a better alternative to what OP was wishing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the file in the banch, but instead of merging your branch into the "Core", you can mege the "core" banche INTO your branch with the deleted file. This way they will always be in sync, but any files you delete will only be deleted in the branches specified.

Comment: Yeah, It is the Core that I need to prune and clear out client specific material from, but yes, that is the end goal that I would only be merging outward from the core to update common features to all branches so the public assets would not be affected.

Comment: Humm...I don't think that is possible. To my knowledge that is not how Git works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a git user, but generically speaking, I believe you should be able to delete the file from the trunk and then during the merge from trunk to the branch, undo that change (e.g. keep or restore the file in the working copy) and then commit the merge.  The changeset should be seen as merged into the branch already in future merges.

Comment: interesting, I'll give it a shot.  (on a test repo of course)

Comment: attempting to test this, but cannot find the right way to "keep or restore the file in the working copy and then commit the merge" in git.

Comment: @jondavidjohn - is git starting the merge okay? are you re-checking out the file or copying a manual backup of the file back to the original name? Are you adding it back into git (via something like `git add` I presume)? Is git rejecting the commit or accepting the commit but simply not adding the file back in?